# How to recursively delete some xml elements using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, recursion

So I got this situation which sucks. I have an XML like this

```
<table border="1" cols="200 100pt 200">
  <tr>
    <td>isbn</td>
    <td>title</td>
    <td>price</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td />
    <td />
    <td>
      <span type="champsimple" id="9b297fb5-d12b-46b1-8899-487a2df0104e" categorieid="a1c70692-0427-425b-983c-1a08b6585364" champcoderef="01f12b93-b4c5-401b-9da1-c9385d77e43f">
        [prénom]
      </span>
      <span type="champsimple" id="e103a6a5-d1be-4c34-8a54-d234179fb4ea" categorieid="a1c70692-0427-425b-983c-1a08b6585364" champcoderef="01f12b93-b4c5-401b-9da1-c9385d77e43f">[nom]</span>
      <span></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Phill It in</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <table id="cas1">
      <tr>
        <td ></td>
        <td >foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td >bar</td>
        <td >boo</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <table id="cas2">
      <tr>
        <td ></td>
        <td >foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td ></td>
        <td >boo</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <table id="cas3">
      <tr>
        <td >bar</td>
        <td ></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td >foo</td>
        <td >boo</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <table id="cas4">
      <tr>
        <td />
        <td />
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>boo</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </tr>
  <table id="cas4">
    <tr>
      <td />
      <td />
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>boo</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <tr>
    <td />
    <td />
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now the question is how would I recursively delete all empty td, tr and table elements?

Now I use this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="td[not(node())]" />
  <xsl:template match="tr[not(node())]" />
  <xsl:template match="table[not(node())]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it doesn't do very well. After I delete td, a tr becomes empty but it doesn't handle that. Too bad. See the **table** element with "cas4".

```
<table border="1" cols="200 100pt 200">
  <tr>
    <td>isbn</td>
    <td>title</td>
    <td>price</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span type="champsimple" id="9b297fb5-d12b-46b1-8899-487a2df0104e" categorieid="a1c70692-0427-425b-983c-1a08b6585364" champcoderef="01f12b93-b4c5-401b-9da1-c9385d77e43f">
        [prénom]
      </span>
      <span type="champsimple" id="e103a6a5-d1be-4c34-8a54-d234179fb4ea" categorieid="a1c70692-0427-425b-983c-1a08b6585364" champcoderef="01f12b93-b4c5-401b-9da1-c9385d77e43f">[nom]</span>
      <span />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Phill It in</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <table id="cas1">
      <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bar</td>
        <td>boo</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <table id="cas2">
      <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>boo</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <table id="cas3">
      <tr>
        <td>bar</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>boo</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <table id="cas4">
      <tr />
      <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>boo</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </tr>
  <table id="cas4">
    <tr />
    <tr>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>boo</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <tr />
</table>
```

#### How would you solve this problem?

Comment: Good question! Anyway, deleting all empty `<td>` nodes might be over the top - they are necessary for keeping a sensible table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is your solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | text()">
        <xsl:copy />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="table | tr | td">

        <!-- result of the transformation of descendants -->
        <xsl:variable name="content">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:variable>

        <!-- if there are any children left then copy myself -->
        <xsl:if test="count($content/node()) > 0">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
                <xsl:copy-of select="$content" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The idea is simple. I will do the transformation for my descendants first and then I will look if there is anyone left. If so I will copy myself and the result of the transformation.

If you want to preserve the table structure and remove only empty rows - elements `<tr>` that contains only empty elements `<td>`, than just create similar template for `<tr>` with different condition and ignore elements `<td>`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | text()">
        <xsl:copy />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="table">

        <!-- result of the transformation of descendants -->
        <xsl:variable name="content">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:variable>

        <!-- if there are any children left then copy myself -->
        <xsl:if test="count($content/node()) > 0">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
                <xsl:copy-of select="$content" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tr">

        <!-- result of the transformation of descendants -->
        <xsl:variable name="content">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:variable>

        <!-- number of non-empty td elements -->
        <xsl:variable name="cellCount">
            <xsl:value-of select="count($content/td[node()])" />
        </xsl:variable>

        <!-- number of other elements -->
        <xsl:variable name="elementCount">
            <xsl:value-of select="count($content/node()[name() != 'td'])" />
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:if test="$cellCount > 0 or $elementCount > 0">
            <xsl:copy>                  
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
                <xsl:copy-of select="$content" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Well, actually the last `if` should be like this:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <!-- if there are cells then copy the content -->
    <xsl:when test="$cellCount > 0">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="$content" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:when>

    <!-- if there are only other elements copy them -->
    <xsl:when test="$elementCount > 0">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="$content/node()[name() != 'td']" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

That is because of the situation when `<tr>` contains empty elements `<td>` and another elements. Then you want to delete the `<td>`s and leave only the rest.

Comment: Thanks, good enough, the only thing to add is to use msxls:node-set($content) when you verify the number of nodes.

Comment: I tested it in XMLSpy and there count($content/node()) works just fine.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like your definition of empty is "contains no text or only whitespace". Is this the case? If so, the following transformation should do the trick:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/> 
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" /> 

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*"> 
    <xsl:copy> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/> 
    </xsl:copy> 
  </xsl:template> 

  <xsl:template match="td[not(normalize-space(.))]" /> 
  <xsl:template match="tr[not(normalize-space(.))]" /> 
  <xsl:template match="table[not(normalize-space(.))]" /> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1 that's clean and pragmatic. Note that `normalize-space(.)` is equivalent to `normalize-space()`

Answer (score 1):

You could also filter out any table that only contains <tr> with empty <td>, and any <tr> with only empty <tr> (in addition to your other filters), using something like this (not tested):

```
<xsl:template match="tr[not(td/node())]" /> 
<xsl:template match="table[not(tr/td/node())]" />
```